# Evaluate integral $\int dx\, \frac{\sin(\alpha\, x)}{\alpha \,x^2}\,\log(x^2)^{-\beta}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have stumbled upon this integral which for the life of me I couldn't solve
$$I(\alpha,\beta,\epsilon)  =\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} dx\, \frac{\sin(\alpha\, x)}{\alpha \,x^2}\,\log(x^2)^{-\beta}$$ where $\alpha >0$ but $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$. Is there  a way to evaluate it in closed form, even the indefinite integral?

To clarify, $\epsilon$ should be intended as such:

$$\mathcal{F}(\alpha,\alpha',\beta) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \,\left[I(\alpha,\beta,\epsilon)-I(\alpha',\beta,\epsilon)\right]  $$

but again, the problem of getting to a closed form aren't related to the limits of integration.

Comment: $F(\alpha, \alpha', \beta)$ definitely has a closed form for $\beta\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: For $\beta<0$ e.g.  $\beta=-1$ Mathematica finds a solution consisting on Hypergeometric functions, means I expect a H-Fox-function of one variable for the general solution.

Comment: $\ln(x^2)^{-\beta}$ can be rewritten as $2^{-\beta}\ln(x)^{-\beta}$. The $2^{-\beta}$ can then be taken out of the integral.

Comment: Wolfram wasn't able to find a solution for $I$. There may be a solution for $\mathcal F$ though

Comment: $\log(x^2)^{-\beta}$ is $\log\left((x^2)^{-\beta}\right)$ or $\left(\log(x^2)^{-\beta}\right)?$

Comment: Its $\left(\log(x^2)\right)^{-\beta}$